# Sharing NFS4 mount accesed by multiple users

Tags: linux, permissions, chmod, nfs

I'm trying to share a NFS mount among multiple users. I can't get it to work, because I always get access denied. I can mount the shares, but I can't see the files.

The export is made through Heartbeat+Pacemaker. I don't think that makes the difference, but here's the export config:

```
primitive exports_nfs_proys ocf:heartbeat:exportfs \
params rmtab_backup="none" directory="/export/proyectos" clientspec="172.16.54.0/24" options="rw,async,no_subtree_check,insecure,root_squash" fsid="2" \
op monitor interval="30s" \
op start interval="0" timeout="240s"
```

So I mount the NFS share:

```
jorge.suarez@decp1304:~$ sudo mount -t nfs4 172.16.54.56:/proyectos/innovacion /mnt
jorge.suarez@decp1304:~$ cd /mnt
bash: cd: /mnt: Permission denied
```

On the client:

```
$ stat /mnt
File: «/mnt»
Size: 3896          Blocks: 0          IO Block: 1048576 directorio
Device: 19h/25d Inode: 131542      Links: 2
Access: (6770/drwsrws---)  Uid: (65534/  nobody)   Gid: ( 3001/proyecto-innovacion)
Access: 2012-08-23 14:47:53.953641353 +0200
Modify: 2012-08-23 14:47:53.263610391 +0200
Change: 2012-08-23 14:47:53.263610391 +0200

jorge.suarez@decp1304:/$ getent group | grep proyecto-innovacion
gproyecto-innovacion:*:3001:diego,felix,jorge.suarez,maria
jorge.suarez@decp1304:/$ getent passwd | grep jorge.suarez
jorge.suarez:*:4004:2000:Jorge Suárez de Lis:/home/remoto/jorge.suarez:/bin/bash
```

On the server:

```
root@ctserv01:/# stat /export/proyectos/innovacion
  File: «.»
  Size: 3896        Blocks: 0          IO Block: 4096   directorio
Device: fb04h/64260d    Inode: 131542      Links: 2
Access: (6770/drwsrws---)  Uid: (65534/  nobody)   Gid: ( 3001/proyecto-innovacion)
Access: 2012-08-23 14:47:53.953641353 +0200
Modify: 2012-08-23 14:47:53.263610391 +0200
Change: 2012-08-23 14:47:53.263610391 +0200

root@ctserv01:/# getent group | grep proyecto-innovacion
proyecto-innovacion:*:3001:diego,felix,jorge.suarez,maria
root@ctserv01:/# getent passwd | grep jorge.suarez
jorge.suarez:*:4004:2000:Jorge Suárez de Lis:/home/remoto/jorge.suarez:/bin/bash
```

So, I'm doing something wrong, but all seems OK here. The UID/GID are matching on client and server.

If I set the directory permissions to 777 I can access, read and write the directory, but I want to restrict this just to some users so that's not an accepted solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you have SELinux disable on server and client

Make sure you use following option in export

```
rw,sync,no_root_squash
```

Make sure you allowed proper subnet or host name etc.

Comment: Actually, the problem solved itself. When I sat down on my desk the next morning, everything worked fine. Nscd was stopped, just in case. I'm using root_squash. Why should I need the no_root_squash option? Everything else is ok :)

Comment: I wan't sure what exactly you plan for NFS. But you are right you don't need no_root_squash because its very dangerous. If no_root_squash is used, remote root users are able to change any file on the shared file system and leave trojaned applications for other users to inadvertently execute.